# Load AngularJS app from backend

Tags: angularjs

First of all, I must say I am surprise I haven't found any resources on this and I'm sorry if I missed something and the question has already been asked

We have a large AngularJS application and would like to :

- Split the app between Landing, Login, Profile and Main modules and only loading the relevant resources (CSS, JavaScript) in order to achieve better load times.
- Check if we have a user logged in on load to avoid redirecting after page load avoid having the inaccessible page blinking in the meantime.

The idea is to have a unique entry point from the application in the backend: `app.py`. The backend would then check the route and check if we have a logged in user. It would then load only the resources associated to the module we are loading, it would also transmit the logged in user to the client side if necessary.

For example, if the user is trying to access `/login` we would check if we have a user logged in from the cookies, if not, we would only load the minified CSS and JavaScript necessary for the login. The landing page especially needs to load very fast so I don't want to load the resources of the entire app when I only need a tiny part of it.

On login, we would reload the page in order for the backend to load the resources of the `Main` module.

This is how `app.py` would look like:

```
from werkzeug.wrappers import Request, Response
import router
import rpc
import assets
import js_globals

@Request.application
def resolve(request):

  # Get the route path : [""], ["login"] or ["logged_in", "editor"] for example 
  route = router.get_route(request)
  # Get the logged in user if any
  user = rpc.authenticate_with_token(request)

  # LoggedIn or Login or Landing
  angular_module = router.get_module(route, user)

  # Load the assets from the module : JavaScript and CSS
  assets_output = assets.load(angular_module)

  if user:
    # Send the user to be available on the client-side 
    js_globals_output = js_globals.set(user)

  output = generate_output(assets_output, js_globals_output)

  return Response(output)
```

My question is: since I haven't been able to see anything like this and AngularJS has been around for a while now, is this the right way to address the issues? Are there better ways to do it?

Thanks!

Comment: You may want to check [angular-require-lazy](https://github.com/nikospara/angular-require-lazy/). It solves the problem of lazy loading/just in time loading using RequireJS. The project is a sample application, I am in the process of componentizing it (bower etc) *and* writing documentation.

Comment: I don't see why AngularJS would have a built-in mechanism for this. It's not what it's designed to do and there's no bulletproof way of achieving this. Some form of lazy resource loading (the RequireJS way seems to be preferred) could work, but having a single combined resource is faster. What you are doing is OK, as long as you stop naming stuff "angular_whatever". As far as your Python code is concerned there's no "Angular". The reverse should also be true.